# Read URL string using JS array to display <DIV> output

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, url, show

I'm a newbie and not a JS guru, so please be patient. ;)

Basically, I am looking to show some content that exists inside DIV tags based upon what is in a URL string.

So, for example, if some form of "window.location" does maybe a "For Each" string match to read a URL like this:  /new_contacts_page.htm?Divs=div1,div3, ...in this case, only div1 and div3 would show, but a div1 and div4 would not.

So, to complicate this a bit, then I would like to allow for any number of desired Divs to show as either expanded or collapsed, so just a header title might show with a [+] to allow for expanding.

So, if we wanted div1 to expand, and div3 to stay collapsed until clicked to expand, the new URL might look like this:  /new_contacts_page.htm?Divs=div1,div3&Expand=div1.

If the URL looked like this:  /new_contacts_page.htm?Divs=div1,div3,div4&Expand=div1,div4, ...then div1, div3, and div 4 would show, but div2 would not, and div1 and div4 would show open/expanded, but div3 would be closed/collapsed.

Hope the description is Ok. ;)

Thanks for any assistance. :)

Erik

Comment: Some quick comments... JQuery probably has some good query string processing tools. I would use lowercase keys, i.e. `?expand=1,2,3` in favor of `?Expand=1,2,3` and I wouldn't always write `div3` etc. but just pass on `3`.

Comment: thanks ljacqu.  the "div#" will actually be listed as something more like abcinc, xyzcompany, as so on, as they will be readable and then understandable for what is in those.  i just put div1/2/3 to make it shorter and easier to read.  i've played with jquery, but again, i am not a guru.  i have found some scripts, but nothing that fits this exact need, and have had issues piecing something together.